# How to cover the whole pie chart with selected portion

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a piechart which is plotting with dynamic values . So if my dataset contains 2 rows then only two slice will be there in piechart if dataset contains 3 rows then 3 slice will get plot and so on.. My question is how to covered the all piechart with the selected slice color without using drilldown.js

Here is the code

```js
init: $(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        colors: ['#3f51b5', '#03a9f4', '#0caf50', '#f9ce1d', '#ff9800', '#007bc1'],
        
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#GridContainer").find(':only-child:last').html() == "No Data Found") {
            $("#InvestorListFilter").hide()
        }
        else
        {
            $("#InvestorListFilter").show()
}
        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container1',
                type: 'pie',
                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                plotShadow: false,
                marginRight: '-25',
                backgroundColor:'#f7f7f7',
                events: {
                    load: function () {
                        requestDataforGeoDispersion(1);
                    },
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Geographical Dispersion',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                align: 'center',
                y: -5,
                x:15,
                style: {
                    color: '#00539b',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontfamily: 'Frutiger Light',
                    padding:0
                }
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '<a style="font-size:smaller;text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointer" href="#">VIEW ALL LABELS</a>',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                //align: 'center',
                //y: 11,
                //x:19,
                style: {
                    color: '#007bc1',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2,
                shared: false,                
                useHTML: true,                               
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<table width=100%><tr><td style="float:right;text-align:center;"><b>' + this.point.name.toUpperCase() + '</b></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><b>SHARES:</b></td><td style="float:right"><b>' + this.point.shareValue + '</b></td></tr><tr><td><b>%IC:</b></td><td style="float:right"><b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '%</b></td></tr>' +
                            '<tr><td><b>NO. INVESTORS:</b></td><td style="float:right"><b>' + this.point.totalNoOfInvestors + '</b></td></tr></table>'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    innerSize: 50,    
                    borderWidth :0,
                    depth: 45,
                    slicedOffset: 0,
                    shadow: false,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',   
                                    
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                    },
                    style: {
                        
                        padding:0
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        color: '#999999',
                        distance: 10,
                        connectorWidth: 0,
                        allowOverlap: true,
                        enabled: true,
                        padding: 0,
                        connectorPadding: 0,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'normal',
                            fontSize: '10px'
                        }
                    },
                },
            },
            exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButtons: {
                        enabled: false,
                        menuItems: null
                    }
                },
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
            }]
        });
        var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container2',
                type: 'pie',
                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
                plotShadow: false,
                marginRight: '-30',
                events: {
                    load: requestDataforGeoDispersion(2)
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Investment Style',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                y: -5,
                x: 15,
                style: {
                    color: '#00539b',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '<a style="font-size:smaller;text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointer" href="#">VIEW ALL LABELS</a>',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                align: 'center',
                y: 11,
                x:19,
                style: {
                    color: '#007bc1',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'                    
                }
            },
            tooltip: {               
                shared: false,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<table width=100%><tr><td style="float:right;text-align:center;"><b>' + this.point.name.toUpperCase() + '</b></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><b>SHARES:</b></td><td style="float:right"><b>' + this.point.shareValue + '</b></td></tr><tr><td><b>%IC:</b></td><td style="float:right"><b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '%</b></td></tr>' +
                           '<tr><td><b>NO. INVESTORS:</b></td><td style="float:right"><b>' + this.point.totalNoOfInvestors + '</b></td></tr></table>'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: false,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    innerSize: 50,
                    depth: 45,
                    borderWidth :0,
                    slicedOffset: 0,
                    shadow: false,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        color: '#999999',
                        distance: 10,
                        enabled: true,
                        allowOverlap: true,
                        connectorWidth: 0,
                        padding: 0,
                        connectorPadding: 0,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'normal',
                            fontSize: '10px'
                        }
                    },
                },
            },
            exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButtons: {
                        enabled: false,
                        menuItems: null
                    }
                },
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
            }]
        });
        var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container3',
                type: 'pie',
                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                plotShadow: false,
                marginRight: '-30',
                backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
                borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
                events: {
                    load: requestDataforGeoDispersion(3)
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Investor Type',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                fontfamily:'Frutiger Light',
                y: -5,
                x:15,               
                style: {
                    color: '#00539b',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'                    
                }
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '<a style="font-size:smaller;text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointer" href="#">VIEW ALL LABELS</a>',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                align: 'center',
                y: 11,
                x:19,
                style: {
                    color: '#007bc1',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    title: 'Manish'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: false,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<table width=100%><tr><td style="float:right;text-align:center;"><b>' + this.point.name.toUpperCase() + '</b></td>'+
                        '<td></td></tr><tr><td><b>SHARES:</b></td><td style="float:right"><b>' + this.point.shareValue + '</b></td></tr>'+
                        '<tr><td><b>%IC:</b></td><td style="float:right"><b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '%</b></td></tr>' +
                           '<tr><td><b>NO. INVESTORS:</b></td><td style="float:right"><b>' + this.point.totalNoOfInvestors + '</b></td></tr></table>'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: false,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    innerSize: 50,
                    slicedOffset: 0,
                    borderWidth :0,
                    depth: 45,
                    shadow: false,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        color: '#999999',
                        distance: 10,
                        connectorWidth: 0,
                        connectorPadding: 0,
                        allowOverlap: true,
                        padding: 0,
                        enabled:true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'normal',
                            fontSize: '10px',
                            //width:'100px'
                        }
                    },
                },
            },
            exporting: {
                buttons: {
                    contextButtons: {
                        enabled: false,
                        menuItems: null
                    }
                },
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{}]
        });
        var chartData = "";
        init: function requestDataforGeoDispersion(flag) {
            var multiselectRegion = $("input[id*=HdnRegionMultiple]").val();
            var multiselectStyle = $("input[id*=hdnInvestmentStyle]").val();
            var multiselectType = $("input[id*=HdnInvestorType]").val();
            var activityChart = $('input[name=m$p1$RadioButtonListTrends]:checked').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "Investors.aspx/GetPieChartDataForGeoDispersion",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{regionID: "' + multiselectRegion + '",styleID: "' + multiselectStyle + '",typeID: "' + multiselectType + '",activityChartValue: "' + activityChart + '" }',
                success: function (data) {
                    chartData = JSON.parse(data.d);  
                    var color="";                 
                    var dataArr = [];
                    if (flag == 1) {
                        $.each(chartData[0], function (index, value) {
                            var sum = parseFloat((value.Sum * 100).toFixed(2));
                            if (sum > 0) {
                                var jsondata = {
                                    name: value.RegionName.toUpperCase(),
                                    y: parseFloat((value.Sum * 100).toFixed(2)),
                                    id: value.InvestorCompanyRegionID,
                                    shareValue: commaSeparateNumber(value.ShareValue),
                                    totalNoOfInvestors: value.TotalNoOfInvestors
                                }
                                dataArr.push(jsondata);
                            }
                        });
                        chart1.addSeries({
                            name: 'GeoDispersion',
                            colorByPoint: true,
                            size: 140,                           
                            allowOverlap: true,
                            point: {
                                events: {
                                    click: function (event) {
                                        event.preventDefault();                                       
                                        $("input[id*=HdnRegionMultiple]").val(this.id);
                                        var chartButtonID = document.getElementsByClassName('chartFilterButton')[0].id;
                                        document.getElementById(chartButtonID).click();    
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                       
                            },
                            data: dataArr,                           
                        });
                        const menu = document.createElement('div');
                        menu.style.cssText = 'left:' + (this.plotLeft + this.plotWidth * 0.5) + 'px; top:' + (this.plotTop + this.plotHeight * 0.1) + 'px; position: absolute; display: none; background-color:white; padding: 20px';

                        let str = '';

                        chart1.series[1].data.forEach(point => {
                            str += '<p><div style="display:inline-block;padding-right: 10px;width:10px;height:10px;background-color:' + point.color + ';background-clip:content-box;"></div>' + point.name + '</p>'
                        });

                        str += '';
                        menu.innerHTML = str;
                        chart1.renderTo.appendChild(menu);

                        chart1.subtitle.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
                            menu.style.display = 'block';
                        })
                        chart1.subtitle.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                            menu.style.display = 'none';
                        })
                    }
                    else if (flag == 2)
                    {
                        var dataArrStyle = [];
                        drilldownSeries = [];
                        
                        $.each(chartData[1], function (index, value) {
                            var sum = parseFloat((value.Sum * 100).toFixed(2));
                            if (sum > 0) {
                                var jsondata = {
                                    name: value.StyleName.toUpperCase(),
                                    y: parseFloat((value.Sum * 100).toFixed(2)),
                                    id: value.InvestorStyleID,
                                    shareValue: commaSeparateNumber(value.ShareValue),
                                    totalNoOfInvestors: value.TotalNoOfInvestors
                                }
                                dataArrStyle.push(jsondata);                            
                            }
                        });                            
                        chart2.addSeries({
                            name: 'InvestmentStyle',
                            colorByPoint: true,
                            enabled: true,                           
                            allowOverlap: true,
                            size: 140,
                            point: {
                                events: {
                                    click: function (event) {
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        $("input[id*=hdnInvestmentStyle]").val(this.id);
                                        var chartButtonID = document.getElementsByClassName('chartFilterButton')[0].id;
                                        document.getElementById(chartButtonID).click();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            data: dataArrStyle,
                        });
                        const menu = document.createElement('div');
                        menu.style.cssText = 'left:' + (this.plotLeft + this.plotWidth * 0.5) + 'px; top:' + (this.plotTop + this.plotHeight * 0.1) + 'px; position: absolute; display: none; background-color:white; padding: 20px';
                        let str = '';
                        chart2.series[1].data.forEach(point => {
                            str += '<p><div style="display:inline-block;padding-right: 10px;width:10px;height:10px;background-color:' + point.color + ';background-clip:content-box;"></div>' + point.name + '</p>'
                        });

                        str += '';
                        menu.innerHTML = str;
                        chart2.renderTo.appendChild(menu);

                        chart2.subtitle.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
                            menu.style.display = 'block';
                        })
                        chart2.subtitle.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                            menu.style.display = 'none';
                        })
                   }
                    else if (flag == 3)
                    {
                        var dataArrType = [];
                        $.each(chartData[2], function (index, value) {
                            var sum = parseFloat((value.Sum * 100).toFixed(2));
                            if (sum > 0) {
                                var jsondata = {
                                    name: value.TypeName.toUpperCase(),
                                    y: parseFloat((value.Sum * 100).toFixed(2)),
                                    id: value.InvestorTypeID,
                                    shareValue: commaSeparateNumber(value.ShareValue),
                                    totalNoOfInvestors: value.TotalNoOfInvestors
                                }
                                dataArrType.push(jsondata);
                            }
                        });                       
                        chart3.addSeries({
                            name: 'InvestorTypes',
                            colorByPoint: true,
                            size: 140,                            
                            data: dataArrType,
                            point: {
                                events: {
                                    click: function (event) {
                                        event.preventDefault();                                       
                                        $("input[id*=HdnInvestorType]").val(this.id);
                                        var chartButtonID = document.getElementsByClassName('chartFilterButton')[0].id;
                                        document.getElementById(chartButtonID).click();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        });
                        const menu = document.createElement('div');
                        menu.style.cssText = 'left:' + (this.plotLeft + this.plotWidth * 0.5) + 'px; top:' + (this.plotTop + this.plotHeight * 0.1) + 'px; position: absolute; display: none; background-color:white; padding: 20px';

                        let str = '';

                        chart3.series[1].data.forEach(point => {
                            str += '<p><div style="display:inline-block;padding-right: 10px;width:10px;height:10px;background-color:' + point.color + ';background-clip:content-box;"></div>' + point.name + '</p>'
                        });

                        str += '';
                        menu.innerHTML = str;
                        chart3.renderTo.appendChild(menu);

                        chart3.subtitle.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
                            menu.style.display = 'block';
                        })
                        chart3.subtitle.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                            menu.style.display = 'none';
                        })
                    }
                },
                cache: false
            });
        }        
    });
    function commaSeparateNumber(val){
        while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
            val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
        }
        return val;
    }
    
});
```

Comment: I am not getting  _covered the all piechart with the selected slice color_ means. Please provide more details . I think you want something like [Synchronized charts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts)

Comment: I want something like in the attached image but without using drilldown js.https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jczp4.png . Color should be the respective slice color. currently in image at right side covering the piechart with blue color . suppose if i click on yellow it should covered with yellow color and so on,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the points' color on point's click event - see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.point.events.click).

On click event, loop through the points and update its color, when the loop is ended, redraw the chart.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie',
        events: {
          load: function () {
            this.series[0].points.forEach(point => {
              point.options.baseColor = point.color;
            });
          }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        data: [
            { name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer', y: 56.33 },
            { name: 'Chrome', y: 24.03 },
            { name: 'Firefox', y: 10.38 },
            { name: 'Safari', y: 4.77 },
            { name: 'Opera', y: 0.91 },
            { name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable', y: 0.2 }
        ],
        innerSize: '40%',
        size: '80%',
        point: {
          events: {
            click: function () {
              this.series.points.forEach(point => {
                point.update({
                  color: this.options.baseColor,
                  dataLabels: {
                    enabled: point === this
                  }
                }, false);
              });
              this.series.chart.redraw();
            }
          }
        }
    }]
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/jvacqt4j/

Comment: Thank You Morgan.. You rock